# Why does this run on main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Very simple code:

```
queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread mainThread]? @"main" : @"not main");    
}];
```

prints "main".

Why? Isn't it suppose to run in bg thread asynchronously, unless i call `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` ?

Answer (score 6):

`[NSThread mainThread]` always returns an object (and thus yielding `YES` when cast to `BOOL`), since there is a main thread when your program is running.

If you want to check whether the current thread is the main thread or not, you need to use the `currentThread` method of `NSThread`.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSThread currentThread] isEqual:[NSThread mainThread]] 
      ? @"main" : @"not main");
```

`NSThread` has a better method; it seems you can use the `isMainThread` method to check whether the current thread is the main thread or not:

```
if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
   //
}
```

Well as user @borrrden pointed out, you just need to use `[NSThread isMainThread]`,

```
if([NSThread isMainThread]){
   //
}
```

See the [`NSThread` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Ahhhh...shit. I thought it returned BOOL indication wether you are calling from main thread or not. thanks.

Comment: @borrrden oops.. how could I miss that? Would you mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra By all means